# Guess characters from pictures

Tags: knowledge, visual

I've been sent this by my friend on Facebook. Unfortunately I don't know the original source. Every picture represents a set of TV characters. Can you guess who they are?

[image]

Comment: Unlike trademarks, copyrights don't transfer into public domain even if the owner takes no action to protect them. So unless you manage to find the copyright owner, you are (very likely) posting someone else's content without attribution. (As it's a single puzzle, it may be up to dispute whether it constitutes a copyrighted "work", but posting it without permission is still dodgy at best.)

Comment: Some of my guess > 8 . rot13(gbz & wreel) , 4..(gva gva) ,5.(qrkgre) ,12 (qrfcvpnoyr zr) ,17 (zvpxl zbhfr)

Comment: Apparently it's not just TV shows, but also movies, judging by, at least, #19.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1.

> The Simpsons

2.

> Mario Bros.

3.

> Batman (@Kraic)

4.

> TinTin (@Swati)

5.

> Dexter (@Swati)

6.

> Wallace and Gromit

7.

> Family Guy

8.

> Tom & Jerry (@Swati)

9.

> Toy Story (@Kraic)

10.

> The Flintstones

11.

> Deadpool (@Stiv)

12.

> Despicable Me (@Swati)

13.

> South Park

14.

> Pinky and the Brain (@Kraic)

15.

> Futurama

16.

> Danger Mouse (@Stiv)

17.

> Mickey and Minnie (@Swati)

18.

> Bugs Bunny (@Stiv)

19.

> Star Wars

20.

> Star Trek

Comment: 16 is rot13(Qnatrezbhfr naq Crasbyq)

Comment: Also, rot13(V fhfcrpg 11 vf Qrnqcbby. Fbzrbar ryfr va zl ubhfr guvaxf 18 vf Ohtf Ohaal (pregnvayl gur gbc cneg zngpurf uvf rnef) ohg V'z lrg gb or pbaivaprq ol gung zbhgu nern...)

Comment: @Stiv; vg'f n pneebg

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps:

> 1: Homer, Marge, Bart, Lisa, Maggie (The Simpsons)
>   2: Mario and Luigi
>   3: Batman
>   4: Tin Tin and Snowy
>   5: Dexter and Dee Dee (Dexter's Laboratory)
>   6: Wallace and Grommit
>   7: Peter, Lois, Chris, Meg, Stewie, Brian (Family Guy)
>   8: Tom and Jerry
>   9: Buzz Lightyear and Woody (Toy Story)
>  10: Fred, Wilma, Dino, Pebbles (The Flintstones)
>  11: Deadpool
>  12: Minions (Despicable Me)
>  13: Stan, Kenny, Kyle, Eric (South Park)
>  14: Pinky and The Brain
>  15: Fry, Leeta, Bender (Futurama)
>  16: Danger Mouse and Penfold
>  17: Mickey and Minnie Mouse
>  18: Bugs Bunny
>  19: Luke, Han, Leia, Chewbacca, C-3PO, R2-D2 (Star Wars)
>  20: Kirk, Spock, Uhura, Scotty (Start Trek)

Got something for everything now ...